# jQuery.html() doesn't recognize class names

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Before I added `loadItems` function,  `$(".ActivateItem").click(function () {...}):` works fine. But when I made jquery code to load items on a table, class name (for I think) is not recognized.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadItems(5);
        function loadItems(rc) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '@Url.Content("~/User/UserList")',
                data: { take: rc },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    var tags = "<tr><th>Login id</th><th>First name</th><th>Middle name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Prefix</th><th>Suffix</th><th>Reset</th><th>Email</th><th></th></tr>";
                    $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                        tags += "<tr id=" + item.UserID + ">" +
                                    "<td>" + item.LoginID + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.FirstName + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.MiddleName + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.LastName + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.Prefix + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.Suffix + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.IsReset + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + item.SendEmail + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" +
                                    "<a href=# class='ActivateItem' data-id = " + item.UserID + " item-data = " + item.LoginID + ">Activate</a> | " +
                                    "<a href=/BaseAdmin/User/Details/" + item.UserID + ">Details</a></td></tr>";
                        alert("<a href=# class='ActivateItem' data-id = " + item.UserID + " item-data = " + item.LoginID + ">Activate</a> | ");
                    });
                    $("#table-list").html(tags);
                }
            });
        };

        $(".ActivateItem").click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            var display = $(this).attr("item-data");
            alert("Hello");
            var answer = confirm("Activate user with login id: " + display);
            if (answer) {
                $.post("/User/Activate", { "id": id },
                    function (data) {
                        if (data > 0) {
                            $("#row-" + data).fadeOut('fast');
                        } else {
                            alert("Data was not deleted successfully.");
                        }
                    });
            }
        });

        $("#rows-count").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                var rowscount = $(this).val();
                loadItems(rowscount);
            }
        });
    });
</script>  

<table id="table-list"></table>
<div id="pager">
    Rows: <input type="text" id="rows-count" />
    <input type="button" id="btn-next" value="Next"/>
    <input type="button" id="btn-back" value="Back" />
</div>
```

The $(".ActivateItem") is not working, what did I missed?
Hope someone could help, or if you have better solution, please share. Thanks!

By the way, this was the old code where `$(".ActivateItem")` works fine:

```
<table id="table-list">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Login id
        </th>
        <th>
            First name
        </th>
        <th>
            Middle name
        </th>
        <th>
            Last name
        </th>
        <th>
            Prefix
        </th>
        <th>
            Suffix
        </th>
        <th>
            Reset
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr id="row-@item.UserID">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LoginID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MiddleName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Prefix)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Suffix)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.IsReset)
                { <text>YES</text>;
                }
                else
                { <text>NO</text>;
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.SendEmail)
                { <text>YES</text>;
                }
                else
                { <text>NO</text>;
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="ActivateItem" data-id = "@item.UserID" item-data = "@item.LoginID">Activate</a> |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.UserID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For elements loaded with AJAX (after the page has completed loaded), you need to use the method live: http://api.jquery.com/live/

So you should change:

```
$(".ActivateItem").click(function(){...})
```

to

```
$(".ActivateItem").live('click', function(){...});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems I see. First, your loadItems function is only available in the anonymous scope of your document ready function. This should be moved somewhere more usefully scoped since you seem to intend to use it to implement paging.

You are currently not finding anything with the class-based selector because the selector is looking for elements before the success callback is called, so no elements have been generated yet. You can either move the execution to within the success callback, or use a dynamic-compatible event binding with jQuery.

Since $().live is deprecated, you should use [$().on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically created elements which need event wiring, unless you are staying on a legacy version of jQuery.

Comment: I have tried **$(".ActivateItem").on("click", function (){})** but it doesn't work. I'm using jquery-1.7.1.js